# How to obtain API documentation for Protractor 4.0.14

Tags: protractor

Due to some issues I'm having with Protractor 5, I am currently using Protractor 4.0.14. I need to get the API documentation for the exact version of Protractor I am using.

Best I understand, the API documentation at the [enter link description here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api) reflects the latest version.

What should I do in order to obtain the API docs for the exact version I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the following steps

1. Checkout the protractor repo and switch to the protractor 4.0.14 tag
2. Read the documentation about how to generate the website [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/website)

You will now have the 4.0.14 version on your local machine

Comment: This is what I had thought to do initially. I managed to revert my cloned git repository to an approximately proper state, but then I could not figure out how to run the web site. I will try the approach you suggested.

Comment: Ok, cool, make sure you are NodeJS 6.9.x and do a "fresh" install of the node modules to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor API v.1.1.1 was on the [official GitHub](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/docs) till Nov 2, 2014. After it date protractor API was removed and pointed to the [website](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api) without availability to change version of API. I have found just a [changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) with a list of API versions.

Comment: Right, there seems to be a shortage of readily available info about past versions' API. Thanks for the link you posted; I will review in detail asap.